# C/C++: replace specific(matching) string in a HTTP header (in a TCP packet)

Tags: c, regex, http, http-headers

I have a program which operates on a HTTP packet, I want to replace the IP address in the HTTP header with new string.

For example, there are string "192.168.0.1" in the HTTP header, and I want to replace it with 10.0.0.1.
so if in the HTTP header the Host field is:

```
Host 192.168.0.1:8000
```

I want to make it

```
Host 10.0.0.1:8000
```

so my basic requirement is to use a regrex over the HTTP header bytes(specifically,right now I focus on for HTTP request), locate the string and replace it. I want to get a function which is like:

```
http_str_replace(char *http_header, char *matching_str, char *new_str, void(*regrex)())
```

in my case, it is

```
http_str_replace(char *http_header, "192.168.0.1", "10.0.0.1", void(*regrex)())
```

I have two questions:

1) are there **endianess** issues in HTTP header bytes? if so, how to deal with it

2) how to determine HTTP header length

3) are there any existing code snippets or regrex functions which is convenient for my usage?

thanks

Comment: Endian is a file reading issue, no a regex issue. Is the packet binary. Specifically, regex works on text. Even if you coerce a (byte*) to (char*), regex engines partition the string into _character unit_ semantics for how many bytes per character (encoding). Beyond that, what regex engine are you using ?

Comment: @sin I'm looking for a regrex function. I'm writing network program, so these packets are captured from network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, there are no issues with endianness with HTTP headers. HTTP headers comprise ASCII *bytes* only, while endianness is mainly an issue when dealing with binary structured data, like the TCP header. In such cases, the OS will provide functions to translate data between host and network byte orders.
2. The only reliable way to know the length of an HTTP header is to receive it all. HTTP headers end at the first empty line found, as per the [section 4 of the RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). You should be careful as it's not strange to find clients that use LF (`'\n'`) for newlines instead of the spec compliant CRLF (`'\r\n'`)
3. There are lots of C regex libraries, one example is [SLRE](https://github.com/cesanta/slre). In their site you can find a simple example of parsing an HTTP request with it. Also, C++11 includes regular expressions within its standard library!